# Proper rawQuery

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I try to query and get just one data with `id = x`.

My `method` is:

```
public Cursor getDataWithId(String id) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from urun_table where ID = "+id,null);
  return res;
}
```

Am I doing this wrong? Because I think, I didn't understand `selectionArgs` correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: Are the actual ID values in the table numbers or strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
String TABLE_URUN = "urun_table";
String KEY_ID = "ID";

public Cursor getDataWithId(String id) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s = ?", TABLE_URUN, KEY_ID);
  Cursor res = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{id});
  return res;
}
```

as in the [rawQuery() documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.CancellationSignal)):

> **selectionArgs**    **String**: You may include ?s in where clause in the query,
>   which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs. The values
>   will be bound as Strings.

So, if you want to use multiple selections for something like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE KEY_ID = id AND KEY_OTHER = otherValue
```

You only need to add multiple "?" and strings in selectionArgs parameter:

```
String KEY_OTHER = "other";

public Cursor getDataWithId(String id, String other) {
  String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s = ? AND %s = ?", TABLE_URUN, KEY_ID, KEY_OTHER);
  Cursor res = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{id, other});
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
public Cursor getDataWithId(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from urun_table where ID = '" + id + "'", null);
    return res;
}
```